# Сокрытие и развертывание текста

Tags: javascript

Как сделать сокрытие и развертывание текста? Т.е. имеется какой-то кусок текста и ниже ссылочка подробнее, по нажатии на неё получаете полный развернутый текст? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function hide(){
obj = document.getElementById('fld');
if(obj){
  if(obj.style.display=='none') obj.style.display='';
    else obj.style.display='none';
 }
}
</script>
<div onClick="hide()" style="cursor:pointer;">поле по которому нажимаем</div>
<div id="fld" style="display:none;">поле которое разворачиваем или сворачиваем</div
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно повесить на ссылку `OnClick=" document.getElementById('нужный id').style.display='block'"`.
Соответственно, по умолчанию дать раскрываемому тексту `style='display:none;'`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery вариант

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#link').click(function(){
    if($('#some_text').is(':visible')){
        $('#some_text').slideUp();
        $(this).text('Показать');
    }
    else{
        $('#some_text').slideDown();
        $(this).text('Скрыть');
    }
    return false;
});
</script>

<a id="link">Показать</a>

<div id="some_text" style="display: none;">
Как сделать сокрытие и развертывание текста? Т.е. имеется какой-то кусок текста и ниже ссылочка подробнее, по нажатии на неё получаете полный развернутый текст? Заранее благодарен.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Существует много вариантов, от подгрузки ajaxом, до увеличение высоты дива или показ скрытого дива